# How To Pick Folder or File Using a Gamepad?

Tags: uwp, winui

UWP has Windows.Storage.Pickers (FileOpenPicker and FolderPicker). There doesn't seem to be any way to use them with a gamepad on a desktop. Creating my own Folder/File picker is an option I guess but it would require the 'broadFileAccess' capability. Is there any other solution or workaround? Does running the app on an Xbox still have this limitation?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers

Comment: What's your real scenario? Are you trying to run your UWP app on Xbox and call the Pickers?

Comment: Using the picker on a desktop with the gamepad.

Comment: Currently, what's the behavior that you are meeting when you trying to use the gamepad in your app for the FileOPenPicker?

Comment: The Windows picker opens. Then the gamepad cannot be used to pick a file/folder or even close the picker. Keyboard and mouse is required. You understand this makes a 10 foot experience impossible for any app where the user must select a folder (such as their personal media content).

Comment: Yes, I've tested this on the desktop, the gamepad can't pick or close the FilePicker. But the gamepad is not designed to use on the desktop. What's the real scenario for the behavior?   Also, the folderpicker is not supported to use on the Xbox platform.  This is mentioned here: [UWP features not supported on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox)

Comment: I've told you the real scenario 3 times. Controlling a 10ft UWP app with a gamepad on a desktop PC, and allowing the user to select their own personal content. Why does this seem like such an odd use case for you? UWP documentation is littered with articles touting its 10ft experience features, controlling apps with just a gamepad or a remote. If broadFileAccess is the only way then just say that. You don't need to try and make excuses for the platform's shortcoming by suggesting I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Why do things like [this](https://gizmodo.com/windows-xbox-game-bar-gains-more-utility-controller-su-1848891290) or [this](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/3725-76D3-3F31-FB63) exist if a gamepad is not designed to use on the desktop? And it seems folder pickers did [used to work](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/ebrrf1/working_alternatives_to_xbox_file_explorer/) on Xbox?

Comment: The description from your comment really sounds like you are developing on Xbox, not a desktop. It makes me want to double-check the real scenario. The Fileopenpicker is designed for desktops with mouse and keyboard so it does not fit the gamepad control. You could submit feedback about this in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform** -> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request.